# [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.1.so.0.1

Tags: wine, odbc, ms-sql

I am trying to run windows command line program that uses ODBC to connect to a remote MSSQL server. It works fine in Windows 10. Now I want to run the same program in Linux using Wine. I have installed unixODBC. ODBC connection is working fine. I can connect to the remote MSSQL server using `isql` command.

But when I run my windows program using wine. I get this error log. What should I do?

`[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib'/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.1.so.0.1`

```
cat /etc/odbcinst.ini
[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.1.so.0.1
UsageCount=1
Trace = Yes
TraceFile = /var/log/odbc.log
```

This file does exist. All dependencies are there too.

```
 ldd /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/li
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd623d5000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f6221cd4000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f6221acc000)
libodbcinst.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbcinst.so.2 (0x00007f62218b7000)
libcrypto.so.1.0.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.2 (0x00007f6221453000)
libkrb5.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00007f6221179000)
libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00007f6220f2e000)
libcurl.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4 (0x00007f6220cae000)
libssl.so.1.0.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.2 (0x00007f6220a45000)
libuuid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007f6220840000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f62204be000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f62201ba000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f621ffa3000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f621fd86000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f621f9e7000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f62222e6000)
libltdl.so.7 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libltdl.so.7 (0x00007f621f7dd000)
libk5crypto.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00007f621f5aa000)
libcom_err.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00007f621f3a6000)
libkrb5support.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00007f621f19a000)
libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00007f621ef96000)
libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f621ed7f000)
libnghttp2.so.14 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnghttp2.so.14 (0x00007f621eb59000)
libidn2.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn2.so.0 (0x00007f621e937000)
librtmp.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librtmp.so.1 (0x00007f621e71a000)
libssh2.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssh2.so.1 (0x00007f621e4ee000)
libpsl.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpsl.so.5 (0x00007f621e2e0000)
liblber-2.4.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblber-2.4.so.2 (0x00007f621e0d1000)
libldap_r-2.4.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap_r-2.4.so.2 (0x00007f621de80000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f621dc66000)
libunistring.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunistring.so.0 (0x00007f621d94f000)
libgnutls.so.30 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30 (0x00007f621d5b6000)
libhogweed.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhogweed.so.4 (0x00007f621d381000)
libnettle.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.6 (0x00007f621d14a000)
libgmp.so.10 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10 (0x00007f621cec7000)
libgcrypt.so.20 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20 (0x00007f621cbb7000)
libsasl2.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsasl2.so.2 (0x00007f621c99c000)
libp11-kit.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0 (0x00007f621c737000)
libidn.so.11 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn.so.11 (0x00007f621c503000)
libtasn1.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.6 (0x00007f621c2f0000)
libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x00007f621c0dc000)
libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0x00007f621bed3000)
```

Comment: `ldd` against it says?

Comment: I have updated my posted with `ldd` dump

Comment: Got any answer? have the same issue...